# How to add a message in form

Tags: sapui5

I have designed a simple form as defined. If I want to add a message down to the checkboxes, how can we add the message? I am expecting output as like this:

[image: Messages below form elements]

```xml
<Label text="..." required="true">
  <layoutData>
    <l:GridData span="L2 M3 S7"/>
  </layoutData>
</Label>
<Select>
  <layoutData>
    <l:GridData span="L2 M3 S5"/>
  </layoutData>
</Select>
<CheckBox text="....">
  <layoutData>
    <l:GridData span="L2 M3 S7"/>
  </layoutData>
</CheckBox>
<TextArea value=" " rows="3">
  <layoutData>
    <l:GridData span="L2 M3 S5"/>
  </layoutData>
</TextArea>
<CheckBox text="...." >
  <layoutData>
    <l:GridData span="L2 M3 S7"/>
  </layoutData>
</CheckBox>
<TextArea value=" " rows="3">
  <layoutData>
    <l:GridData span="L2 M3 S5"/>
  </layoutData>
</TextArea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am expecting output as like this:
>
> [image]

- For the `CheckBox`, use the property `text`.
- For the character limit message below the `TextArea`, there are two options:

  1. Without `value`-binding: simply define `maxLength` and set `showExceededText="true"`.
  2. With `value`-binding: bind `value` with the type `sap.ui.model(.odata).type.String` and `maxLength: 150`. UI5 will handle displaying message accordingly if the character limit is exceeded. See the documentation topic *[Error, Warning, and Info Messages](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/62b1481d3e084cb49dd30956d183c6a0)* for more information.

```js
sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(() => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/Fragment",
  "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
  "sap/ui/core/Core",
], (Fragment, JSONModel, Core) => Fragment.load({
  definition: `<App xmlns="sap.m" autoFocus="false">
    <Page class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding" showHeader="false">
      <HBox renderType="Bare" justifyContent="SpaceAround">
        <CheckBox text="My custom checkbox text" />
        <TextArea xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" core:require="{ StringType: 'sap/ui/model/type/String' }"
          value="{
            path: '/value',
            type: 'StringType',
            constraints: {
              maxLength: 150
            }
          }"
          maxLength="150"
          width="100%"
          height="5.5rem"
          showExceededText="true"
        >
          <layoutData>
            <FlexItemData maxWidth="13rem"/>
          </layoutData>
        </TextArea>
      </HBox>
    </Page>
  </App>`,
}).then(control => Core.getMessageManager().registerObject(control.setModel(new JSONModel({
  value: "",
})).placeAt("content"), true))));
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core, sap.m"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_fiori_3"
  data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-xx-waitfortheme="init"
></script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact"></body>
```

[image]

If the limit is exceeded (with `value`-binding and `type`):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve it by using `VBox` control

```
<CheckBox text="Custom Note">
    <layoutData>
        <l:GridData span="L2 M3 S6"/>
    </layoutData>
</CheckBox>
<VBox>
    <TextArea value=" " rows="3" />
    <Label text="Max allowed chars 150" wrapping="true"/>
    <layoutData>
        <l:GridData span="L2 M3 S6"/>
    </layoutData>
</VBox>
<CheckBox text="Exception" >
    <layoutData>
        <l:GridData span="L2 M3 S6"/>
    </layoutData>
</CheckBox>
<VBox>
    <TextArea value=" " rows="3"/>                                     
    <Label text="Max allowed chars 150" wrapping="true"/>
    <layoutData>
        <l:GridData span="L2 M3 S6"/>
    </layoutData>
</VBox>
```

**Output**

[image]